# MavenCli doMain() method build log to LOGGER.info instead of System.out

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons-logging, printstream

I am using maven cli to run maven command from Java. Since the below method accepts only `PrintStream` object as input, how do I write maven build log to `Logger` instead of `System.out`. I am not trying to put all of system.out and system.err onto logger. All I need is to pass the argument to MavenCli domain() method so that I can redirect the method(build) logs to Logger.

```
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
Integer result = cli.doMain(new String[]{"clean","package","-Dmaven.test.skip=true"},
                pathToPom,
                System.out, System.out);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Build log is being written to temp text file. 
     MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
     String dir = AppProperties.getEnvProperty("queue");
     PrintStream stdout = new PrintStream( new File("temp.txt") ); 
     result = cli.doMain(new String[]{"clean","package","-Dmaven.test.skip=true"},
                        pathToPom,
                        stdout, stdout);